# Find and replace the rows of an array having repeated number by a fixed given row

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I have a matrix having rows with repeated numbers. I want to find those rows and replace them with a dummy row so as to keep the number of rows of the matrix constant.

```
Dummy_row = [1 2 3]
```

(5x3) Matrix A

```
A = [2 3 6;
     4 7 4;
     8 7 2;
     1 3 1;
     7 8 2]
```

(5x3) Matrix new_A

```
new_A = [2 3 6;
         1 2 3;
         8 7 2;
         1 2 3;
         7 8 2]
```

I tried the following which deleted the rows having repeated numbers.

```
y = [1 2 3]
w = sort(A,2)
v = all(diff(t,1,2)~=0|w(:,1:2)==0,2)  %  When v is zero, the row has repeated numbers
z = A(w,:)
```

Can you please help?

Comment: How can this code be modified such that it also replaces any rows having at least one zero with the Dummy_row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bsxfun` based solution -

```
%// Create a row mask of the elements that are to be edited
mask = any(sum(bsxfun(@eq,A,permute(A,[1 3 2])),2)>1,3);

%// Setup output variable and set to-be-edited rows as copies of [1 2 3]
new_A = A;
new_A(mask,:) = repmat(Dummy_row,sum(mask),1)
```

Code run -

```
A =
     2     3     6
     4     7     4
     8     7     2
     1     3     1
     7     8     2
new_A =
     2     3     6
     1     2     3
     8     7     2
     1     2     3
     7     8     2
```

Comment: Only downside: You'll still need to use `sort(A,2)` to generalize this to matrices with more than 3 columns.

Comment: @knedlsepp You need to edit dummy_row `[1 2 3]` for that, rest of the code stays the same.

Comment: Don't you need n-choose-2 comparisons with n number of columns, if you don't sort?

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry! I misinterpreted `permute(A, [1,3,2])` for `A(:,[2,3,1])`.

Comment: @knedlsepp That's being taken care by permuting `A` and then summing along dim-3 and detecting the ones that exceed `2`. It's a bit a complicated, but if you break it down, it should get clear :)

Comment: Yeah. Get it now. I initially thought you were just shuffling the columns to compare A with A(:,[2,3,1]), which would only work with 3 columns. :-)

Comment: How can i modify this code such that it also replaces any rows having at least one zero with the Dummy_row?

Comment: @AmitSookun `new_A(any(A==0,2),:) = repmat(dummy_row,sum(any(A==0,2)),1)` I think.

Answer (score 3):

See if this works for you,

```
A= [ 2 3 6;
     4 7 4;
     8 7 2;
     5 5 5;
     1 8 8;
     1 3 1;
     7 8 2 ];
Dummy_row = [1 2 3];
b = diff(sort(A,2),1,2);
b = sum(b == 0,2);
b = b > 0;
c = repmat(Dummy_row,sum(b),1);
b = b' .* (1:length(b));
b = b(b > 0);
newA = A; 
newA(b,:) = c;
```

gives,

```
newA =
 2     3     6
 1     2     3
 8     7     2
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 1     2     3
 7     8     2
```

## Edit

Not much change is needed, try this,

```
Dummy_row = [1 2 3];
b = sum(A == 0,2);
b = b > 0;
c = repmat(Dummy_row,sum(b),1);
b = b' .* (1:length(b));
b = b(b > 0); 
newA = A; 
newA(b,:) = c;
```

Comment: I've been waiting for you. Sophisticated! +1

Comment: Thank you @Kamtal! How can this code be modified such that it also replaces any rows having at least one zero with the Dummy_row?

Comment: Thank you very much @Kamtal ! The code performs correctly for the case of having a zero in a row. But i wanted the code to replace the rows when there is either a repeating number or a zero in a particular row. I truly appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following:

```
hasRepeatingNums = any(diff(sort(A, 2), 1, 2)==0, 2); 
A(hasRepeatingNums,:) = repmat(Dummy_row, nnz(hasRepeatingNums), 1);
```

Comment: This could be the fastest!

Comment: Yes definitely! Thank you very much Divakar.

Comment: Thank you @knedlsepp ! How can i modify this code such that it also replaces any rows having at least one zero with the Dummy_row?